# how to remove empty spaces between '=' and values in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I read data from a file and parse them to store in some variables. Data are written as below in the file,

```
INT_VALUE           =                   17 # Valid Integer
INT_VALUE1                              23
INT_VALUE2          =                   00012
INT_VALUE3                             -2
INT_VALUE4                             -33
```

In some places there are spaces and '=' in some other places. While reading I get my stream%val with '='and my value comes as `' =       17'` of which I need to remove = and the spaces between '=' symbol and the first number and store as a valid number.

In some other cases there might be spaces between the numbers which should be an error.

Invalid values will be any non integer/real values with special characters. For example,

```
INT_VALUE13                            34=5434
INT_VALUE14                            -23 45-33
INT_VALUE15         =                  23-45*665Rtre
INT_VALUE16                            -23.4
INT_VALUE17                            1.4E9r23
INT_VALUE18                            -5.D-3.3
INT_VALUE19                            233 ddf
INT_VALUE20                            -87 dfsdf
INT_VALUE21         =                  rtmr,t23./
```

How do I remove the spaces in fortran?

My function is,

```
character(60) function sweep_blanks(in_str)
    character(*), intent(in) :: in_str
    character(60) :: out_str
    character :: ch
    integer :: j
    out_str = " "
    do j=1, len_trim(in_str)
        ch = in_str(j:j)
        if (ch .ne. " ") then
            out_str = trim(out_str) // ch
        endif
        sweep_blanks = out_str
    end do
end function sweep_blanks
```

This removes all blanks irrespective of in the middle or at the end or at the beginning which doesn't help.

Comment: Welcome, please show your code. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the two functions `index` and `adjustl`.

- `index` finds the location of a substring within a string;
- `adjustl` makes leading blanks trailing blanks.

  integer idx
  idx = INDEX(instring, '=')+1
  outstring = ADJUSTL(instring(idx:))

So, given the input string

```
instring = ' =        17'
```

the `index` result will be `2`, giving `idx` value `3`.  `instring(3:)` has the value `'        17'` from which `adjustl`' returns `'17        '`

Given the input string

```
instring = '                    -33'
```

without the `'=`' the `index` result will be `0`.

Comment: Thank you @francescalus , it works but still I am having some issues.

If my value is,

INT_VALUE5         =                   -33ang=344
INT_VALUE6                              -34=174

In both cases it should be invalid but I get the values 344 and 174 as valid values after the '='

Comment: your comment is rather vague. can you explain more or add it as part of the question to make it more clear? What is specifically defined as invalid in your work? Are the two numbers separated by space, a single number separated by mistake?

Comment: @DeenadayalanS, it looks like that problem is different from the splitting, more on parsing the final portion of the string.  If so, then perhaps you could ask that as a different question (linking to this one for context if necessary).